# Return a linked list node and then delete it

Tags: c, linked-list, return-value, free

Below is a function that I wrote that traverses a linked list and returns the node with the lowest value for 'frequency'. However in the main code I call it twice in succession. How can I have it so the code returns the node and then deletes it, so that when it runs again it doesn't return the same node as before? Whats confusing me is that how can I delete the node and then return it if it no longer exists.

```
struct LetterFrequencyPair* lowestF()
{
    int val = 1000;
    struct LetterFrequencyPair* temp;
    struct LetterFrequencyPair* lowest = malloc(sizeof(struct 
LetterFrequencyPair));
    temp = root;
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            if (temp->frequency < val)
            {
                lowest->character = temp->character;
                lowest->frequency = temp->frequency;
                val = lowest->frequency;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        printf("%c\t%d\n", lowest->character, lowest->frequency);
        return lowest;
}
```

Comment: You can't.  The caller is responsible for deleting it.  Call the function, use the result, and delete it when you no longer need it.

Comment: @TomKarzes so if i create a new node (eg low1) and do the following: low1=lowest. and then free(lowest) and rearrange the list to compensate for the deletion, will I be able to use low1 or would that data have been deleted too?

Comment: @OllieParsons the data that `lowest` points to is free'd which means it is no longer marked in the heap as owned by your program and should not be accessed anymore (after `free(lowest)`, both `*lowest` and `*low1` will be invalid since they point to the same address)

Comment: @SimonDoppler Ah ok. How would you recommend overcoming my issue? If the data goes how can i call it twice without getting the same value or losing the value that has been free'd?

Comment: @SimonDoppler OP is creating duplicate of node having the lowest frequency. The `lowest` is not pointing to any node in the list.

Comment: @OllieParsons Since you are creating a duplicate node (named `lowest`) of the node with lowest frequency in the list and returning it, so you can delete the node with lowest frequency from the list in `lowestF()`. But I would suggest to reiterate the requirement once again or at the least rename the function from `lowestF()` to something like `delete_lowestF()` because that's what it would be doing then.

Comment: @H.S. How can I ensure I delete the correct one as it keeps traversing the list incase there's a smaller value. So I couldn't free(temp) at the end as it would be the last node in the list.

Comment: @OllieParsons Take pointer of type `struct LetterFrequencyPair*` say `temp1` and in `if (temp->frequency < val)` block, assign the `temp` to `temp1` like this `temp1 = temp`. When the `while` loop finishes, the `temp1` will be pointing to the node with lowest frequency, if there is any with frequency less than `1000`.